# How can I mark files or folders as "okay to delete" so my OS can manage disk space on its own?

Tags: linux, filesystems

A lot of files that we delete, we delete because we think "I have to delete files that are not needed anymore". But this is often a grey area. I have a couple of sets of backups of my previous phones on my machine. That accumulates some 100gb of data.

On linux, it's either `rm` or not `rm`. I know that the files still exist on the disk, but the pointer is deleted. Is it possible to do something similar but 1 level higher, meaning that I mark folders as "can be deleted when space is required"? When my disk space hits say 80% usage, each time the usage passes 80%, files get deleted (in some logical order) until the threshold is not passed anymore. This way, I don't delete files, I just say "I probobably won't need this anymore". It serves literally no purpose to prematurely delete files in anticipation of future space requirements.

Comment: This looks exactly like what the trash bin of your desktop is doing... But I disagree about "*no purpose to prematurely delete files in anticipation of future space requirements*". Keeping the disk almost full means that the same blocks are used over and over and accumulate wear. On a less full disk the wear can be distributed more evenly.

Comment: I would agree that using the same blocks is bad, hence the idea of the 80% rule which is a common recommendation for SSDs. That said, the trash bin is actually something I completely forgot about as I've been using i3 and mostly terminal based tools over the last years.

Comment: See the `trash-cli` package (on Debian/Ubutnu) to use the trash from the command line, then.

Comment: So instead of being aware and proactive about what you deleted you want to end up in a situation where files are missing and you won't be able to  tell whenever it was because your latest OS update temporarily needed more storage to unpack/pack files or whenever your machine might be having an actual issue? As others said the best compromise would be trash bin.

Comment: As an example: Say I have 4TB of disk storage. I have about 500GB of old windows/linux/phone installation iso files, another 2TB of movies / tv shows etc. I'd like to mark these as "delete when needed" because my stream of data going into this disk is only personal photos which have a higher rank of importance.

Comment: This said, I recognize that this is a niche problem because I use a non-standard desktop environment and the trash is the most common way to approach this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the very behavior of a desktop trashbin. On Linux this The behavior is specified by the FreeDesktop initiative, so all desktop managers work the same way (using the same files/directpries...).

In addition to the desktop GUI, there is a CLI interface to it: install the `trash-cli` package in Debian/Ubuntu. This provides commands such as `trash`, `restore-trash`, etc...